# Fetch 2 querys at once

Tags: php, mysql, sql, fetch

I have 2 tables, in 1 table there are lists of all the episodes from a movie and in the other table there are the streams from the episode. Every episode got his own id so the streams are linked via the id from the episode.

But now I have a problem: I want to make a episode-list and at the same time I want to insert a link to the stream. So that means that I have to fetch 2 tables at the same time but I don't know how. This is my code

```
    <?php
include 'connection.php';
$a = (int)$_GET['a'];

if ($result = $con->prepare("SELECT id, ep_nr, ep_title FROM anime_episode WHERE ani_id = $a"))
{
    $result->execute();
    $result->bind_result($eid, $nr, $title);

    while ($result2 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM anime_stream WHERE ep_id = $eid"))
    {
        $result2->execute();
        $result2->bind_result($eid, $etitle, $lang, $sname, $link, $uploadedby);

echo '<div id="list-box">';
    echo '<table cellspacing="0">';

while ($result->fetch() && $result2->fetch()) 
    {   
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td width="50">' . $nr . '</td>' . '<td>' . $title . '</td>' . '<td>' . $link. '</td>';   
    echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
echo '</table>';
    }
}
$con->close();  
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As Strawberry suggests, I believe your looking to join the two table based on the foreign key and select the content of both tables, somethig like...

```
select
  epi.*,
  str.*
from
  anime-episode epi
inner join
  anime-stream str on epi.ani-id = str.epi-id
where 
  epi.ani-id = $id
```

This assumes that your episodes will always have at least one stream as an inner join will only return a row (with the column of both tables) when a record is found in each of the tables of the join. A Left Outer join can be used which will still return movies even if no streams exist for a given episode.

Can't find underline on my tablet!

Answer (score 0):

A query something like this should do the trick.

```
SELECT ae.id, ae.ep_nr, ae.ep_title, as.* FROM anime_episode ae 
   LEFT JOIN anime_stream as ON as.ep_id = ae.id 
WHERE ae.ani_id = [$arg]
```